# Making functions to print first and last 10 elements of array

Tags: python, arrays, list, element

I couldn't find anything related to printing the first 10 and last 10 elements of an array that's imported from a text file. Here's what I need to do:

- Add in a function will print the first ten elements of the array.
- Add in a function that will print the last ten elements of the array.
- Use the len() function to get the size of the array.
- Use your functions to print the first ten elements of the array and then the last ten elements.
- Then sort the Array from highest to lowest.
- Use your functions to print the first ten elements of the array and then the  last ten elements of the sorted array.

Heres my code: Ignore the average and sum because it is needed for the an other part of the program.

```
def avgcalc(myList):
   intTotal = 0
   intCount = 0;
   intLenMyList = len(myList)

while(intCount <  intLenMyList):
   intTotal += myList[intCount]
   intCount += 1
return intTotal/intLenMyList

def sum1(myList):
  sum = 0
for element in myList:
    sum+=element
print (sum)

def ten(myList):
 for item in myList[:10]:
   print(item)


arr_intValues = []
myFile = open("FinalData.Data", "r")
print("File read complete")
for myLine in myFile:
    arr_intValues.append(int(myLine))



print (avgcalc(arr_intValues))
print (sum1(arr_intValues))
ten(myList)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your code block.

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: Asking how I print the first 10 elements and the last 10 elements from the file

Comment: What you have been assigned to do is not the same as asking a question. With your current code here I would get `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - What is your actual issue; if we ignore `avgcal` and `sum1` then you're asking us to write code for your objectives from scratch?

Comment: As others have pointed out: 1) please fix your indentation.  2)show us the error traceback you get 3) put up a stripped down reproducible code.

Comment: Im getting myList is not defined when trying to print the first and last ten elements of the array how do I fix it this is my issue

Comment: @myhstery Please edit your question and include all the info. And please use proper formatting while you do it. Read through the link that says "how to ask above."

Comment: @myhstery: Please use a proper description. There is no "[array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) that's [imported](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) from a text file". There is a `list` with data that is read from a text file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `myList`, or simply pass `arr_intValues` into the function call for `ten`, i.e.

```
 ten(arr_intValues)
```

Print the first ten (as you do above)

```
for item in myList[:10]:
    print (item)
```

Print the last ten

```
for item in myList[-10:]:
    print (item)
```

Comment: I've tried that but it tells me myList is not defined

Comment: Maybe because `myList` is not defined ? = P

Comment: See my edits above. As Adrien said `myList` was not defined.

Comment: Thanks I did that, now it prints all the numbers from the array.

Comment: `myList[10:]` does not return the first 10 elements of myList, it returns all elements from index 10 through the rest of the list.

Comment: Then how would I print the first and last ten which is what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @myhstery See my answer.

Comment: I tried that and it printed out the first ten and then the last 5, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Read a file into a list, one element per line:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

Print the first 10 elements of the list:

```
print("\n".join(lines[:10]))
```

Print the last 10 elements of the list:

```
print("\n".join(lines[-10:])
```